# Printing alternate elements of a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am having trouble executing the code for Printing alternate elements of a string array.

I have declared a string "welcome" and I want to read the alternative elements like "W, l, o, etc.

```
//Print alternate elements of a string array.

public class AlternateStringArray {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       String str[]= new string[] {"Welcome"};

       for (int i=0; i<7; i+2){

       System.out.println(str[i]);

    }
  }
}
```

---

Receiving the below error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from string[] to String[]

Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to string

Syntax error on token "+", invalid AssignmentOperator
```

**Please help.**

Comment: The error message says it all - remember that the Java language is case-sensitive...  But this won't do what you want as a String is not the same thing as a character array.

Comment: JaVa iS cAse SeNsItIvE.

Comment: 1. `string[] to String[]` 2. `i+2 should be i+=2`. Though your str[0] = Welcome. So is this what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
String str = "Welcome";
char[] strChars = str.toCharArray();
for(int i = 0; i < strChars.length; i += 2) {  // go through all the characters
    System.out.println(strChars[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
String str[]= new string[] {"Welcome"};

to: 
String str[]= new String[] {"Welcome"};
```

For the follow error:

```
Syntax error on token "+", invalid AssignmentOperator

for (int i=0; i<7; i++){

if(i%2 == 0) 
{
   System.out.println(str[i]);
}
```

}

Comment: Changed string to String.Getting the below error now:                       Syntax error on token "+", invalid AssignmentOperator

Comment: @user3220565 - i+2 needs to be assigned to something... Do i=i+2; in your loop.. it will work.. paolo.. +1 for your effort... from next time around explain your code...

Comment: Its showing an output, but not alternative elements. Same element "Welcome" is displayed in output.

Answer (score 1):

as every one stated:

change:

```
String str[]= new string[] {"Welcome"};
```

to:

```
String str[]= new String[] {"Welcome"};
```

**but why**?

so here's my answer:

java is strictly binded object oriented programming language.
everything here is either class, object or method.

In Java, when you do:

```
String xyz = new String("abc");
```

You force the creation of a new String object of `String class`, this takes up some time and memory at time of creation.

but `string` on the other hand is treated as `literal`; which can't have its objects. and thus the error.

**for the second error** :

we know that the syntax of for statement is,

`for(initialization; condition;`**`increment/decrement`**`)`

so as you note third condition isn't satisfiable in `i+2`,
so change it to `i=i+2` or in short `i+=2`.

thus you're getting that error.

Also ***you're creating array of String objects***. in which **`str[0]`th element is your string `"Welcome"`**.
to access character from string at certain position we use `charAt(int position)` method for string objects.

so here to access characters from `0`th string of `str` array, we'll use:

**`str[0].charAt(position)`**.

Thus your final working code'll be:

```
public class AlternateStringArray {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       String str[]= new String[] {"Welcome"};  //note change 
       for (int i=0; i<7; i=i+2){  //note change 
           System.out.println(str[0].charAt(i)); //note change
    }
  }
}
```

also **instead of using fixed length `i<7`**, i'll suggest to **get the length of string dynamically** using **`.length()`** method. as:

**`i<str[0].length()`**.

so the code now is :

```
public class AlternateStringArray {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       String str[]= new String[] {"Welcome"};  //note change 
       for (int i=0; i<str[0].length(); i+=2){  //note change 2
           System.out.println(str[0].charAt(i)); //note change
    }
  }
}
```

***always do understand your code before writing it*** :-)..

hope it'll help you.... cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

```
String str[]= new string[] {"Welcome"};
```

should be

```
String str[]= new String[] {"Welcome"};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error.

```
 String str[]= new string[] --> String str[]= new String[]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are expecting to do.

```
String str[] = new String[] { "Welcome" };
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i += 2) {
        char c = str[0].charAt(i);
        System.out.println(c);
}
```

But whatever approach you are using is not at all valid for many reasons. As Vakh has said you can use that kind of approach , clean and easy to understand.

OR something like this.

```
String str = new String("Welcome");
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 2) {
        System.out.println(i + "::" + str.charAt(i));
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure whats the use of "str.toCharArray()".. Is it a function to remember ?

Comment: nopes it converts your string to new character array. Refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Despite "welcome" already a string [character] array, why is it necessary to convert into character array?

Comment: there you are getting it wrong. as you can see `welcome` is assigned to `str[0]` and not like `str[0] = w ...str[1]=e` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Change your line

```
String str[]=new string[]{"Welcome"};
```

to-

```
String str[]=new String[]{"Welcome"};
```

Comment: Well, you've actually stated the error in the program.. try fixing it! :)

Answer (score 0):

public class PrintAlternativeCharacters {

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    String str = "ROCKSTAR";
    String newStr="";

    //EXPECTED OUT PUT :: OR-KC-TS-RA

    char[] a = str.toCharArray();

    System.out.println("*****************"+a.length);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i=i+2)
    {
        newStr=newStr+str.charAt(i+1)+str.charAt(i);
    }


    System.out.println(newStr);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty late but may this answer help someone. I used java 8 and you can do this in one line of code.

Let's say we have List of String as below (you can take String array and create a list of it)

special

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("A","B","C","D","E","F","G");
```

In such case always get range of IntStream add filter like below

```
IntStream.range(0, names.size()).filter(f -> f%2 == 1)
```

if you print above line of code, it is going to print odd element (elements on 1, 3, 5 etc.) as filter condition is f%2 == 1 and if you want to get even elements, then change filter as f%2 == 0, this will give you elements at 0, 2, 4 etc.

Now it's just matter of getting elements from the list, to do this, you can use function *`mapToObj`* as below

**To get Odd element from the list**

```
IntStream.range(0, names.size()).filter(f -> f%2 == 1).mapToObj(names::get).forEach(System.out::println);
```

**To get even element from the list**

```
IntStream.range(0, names.size()).filter(f -> f%2 == 0).mapToObj(names::get).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Your specific problem

```
List<String> welcome = Arrays.asList("Welcome".split(""));
IntStream.range(0, newA.size()).filter(f -> f%2 == 0).mapToObj(newA::get).forEach(System.out::println);
```

This will print exactly what you want!

Happy coding!